# mAP using Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

After I train my object detector using the Tensorflow object detection API(to detect only cars), I get an mAP value around 0.32 while running the eval.py script. However, in the Tensorflow Detection model Zoo page(which can be accessed at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md), the mAP's for various models are 100 times the value I have obtained but when I look at my model's predictions on the test set, they are actually pretty good. Should I multiply the value which I have obtained by 100 or is there something wrong with the model that I have trained?

Comment: your 0.32 is equal to TFOD's 32.